# Why font size box was removed from WYGWAM

Tags: wygwam

I have posted my problem under some other thread too. Just want help in restoring the ditto content within a WYGWAM field type after an EE upgrade and WYGWAM version upgrade. 
The versions upper than 2.6 are not showing font size drop down. Is this explicitly removed? Can we get this option back? Is this really worthy to remove this kind of option?

Answer (score 3):

The font size button added inline CSS, which is bad practice for modern web development.

The better method is to add a [custom style set](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/using/style_set.html) with semantic, re-usable classes like `.important` or `.featured` that the user can apply to their content.

If you have existing content that used the font size button, you can preserve those styles by setting the "Restrict allowed HTML?" option to "no" in the editor configuration. This will prevent Wygwam from stripping out inline styles.